# Activity Monitor on Mac OS doesn't show port 8080

Tags: macos, network, activity-monitor

I'm trying to verify that a specified process (server) listens on port **8080** using **Activity Monitor**. But, for some strange reason, Activity Monitor doesn't show information about port numbers **greater than 25XX**. I do know that the server works fine and listens on this port.

How can I see the process which listens on port 8080 in Activity Monitor?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it easily in Activity Monitor but it *is* easy at the command line. `lsof -i :8080` in the Terminal will display the command and process ID of the process listening on port 8080.